# Настройки путей к модулям (пакетам)

Tags: package, библиотеки, perl

Насколько я понял все perl библиотеки хранятся в `/usr/local/lib/perl/`

А если к этому каталогу нет доступа, то возможно ли как-то в массив **@INC** подгрузить пути к своим библиотекам и каким образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно модифицировать эту переменную.

библиотеки можно:

- подгрузить с помощью Вашего менеджера пакетов (в федоре - yum).
- с помощью cpan, который сам все установит и все переменные настроит.
- определить переменную окружения [PERL5LIB](http://modperlbook.org/html/3-9-2-2-Using-the-PERL5LIB-environment-variable.html).
- используйте прагму lib `use lib '/home/your_name/perl5_dir';`.

Comment: подгрузить с помощью Вашего менеджера пакетов (в федоре - yum).
с помощью cpan, который сам все установит и все переменные настроит.
я снимаю хостинг из за этого я не могу не как выполнять на нём консольные команды если бы у меня была выделенка или на своём пк то другое дело
другие методы что вы описали щя по читаю и посмотрю )

Comment: вот это (о том, что у Вас нет доступа к консоли) и нужно уточнять в вопросе.

Comment: @Lecome, для установки своих модулей (если они не тянут никаких особых системных зависимостей и/или не требуют спецпроцедур по собрке) достаточно положить их в каталог основого скрипта :) Ну, или, создать там каталог `lib`, скопировать модули в него и в скрипте написать `use lib 'lib';`. Консоли для этого не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Как установить модуль в нестандартный каталог](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module-library-directory-)
2. [Как подключать модули из нестандартных каталогов](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-INC-at-runtime-)